# Bootstrap Datepicker - Issues with <IE9

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

First off, sorry I can't get much to you for a working example. My build is currently only on my localhost and the dev server it gets pushed to is intranet only with passwords that only my office can use. Otherwise, I'd get you all a working example. I'm mostly just curious to see if this is a problem for other people.

I am having a problem with datepicker not selecting a date other than the current date, which is defaulted in the box. It works just fine in all browsers besides IE8 and IE7. These browsers will open the datepicker UI just fine and will allow you to click on a date. However, when you click the date stays the same as your current default date. The UI closes like it should.

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ <-- I am using this for my bootstrap datepicker. I am using jQuery 1.8.2 which is the version this is using as well. I am getting a console error on all browsers for this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined (bootstrap-datepicker.js:379)

I have been messing around for about 45 minutes now trying different things to get it to work. **Interesting part:** I went on the bootstrap datepicker website I included above and viewed it in IE8. It's broken there as well, but the error doesn't display. I believe the error doesn't have anything to do with this not working and just a simple "bootstrap is not compatible with legacy IE browsers" problem. I am looking for confirmation so I can let people know.

Thanks for your knowledge on this: I've done a ton of responsive builds and I have used the jQueryUI datepicker constantly before as well. However, this particular client requested Bootstrap and the Datepicker plugin/theme for it and I have never touched either of them. I spent the past 6 hours working on getting IE8 and IE7 looking normal and acting responsively so my head is a little empty. I appreciate your help!

Other notes: It is not an issue with emulations of IE. This is happening exactly the same in both native IE8 and IE7 as well as emulated IE8/IE7. The piece of code around the error I included above, for those interested, is:

```
    parseDate: function (date, format) {
    var parts = date.split(format.separator),
        date = new Date(),
        val;
    ect...
```

If I console.log date.split(format.separator) I receive "1/16/2013" and it loops again to the next day as well. Val is an incremental number, and I feel I don't need to explain what new Date() is.

Comment: anyway you can build a fiddle as an example?

Comment: I was kind of hoping I can get someone to look at the bootstrap datepicker site I linked and test it out there as well, because I am using basically the same thing. I am working on a fiddle example right now, but I was hoping in the mean time I can get some answers on if it's an legacy IE issue, because if it is then my question is immediately answered and I can move on. :)

Comment: I actually just tested http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/  in IE8 8.0.6001.18702 ..  The first two will not change dates.. but the rest will - I see no errors in the console either

Comment: Well, I might wind up using the other two and explain to my people about what I have to do. Feel like it'll be easier at this point than to figure out what datepicker is doing since I have about fifty different data tables on different pages displaying a ton of information all relevant by date. Bootstrap kind of pushed datepicker into the datatables script that came with it. Thanks so far, I will get a fiddle up soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up finding out that, in general, the in-line boostrap datepicker does **not** work with IE8 and lower. I wound up uninstalling bootstrap datepicker and using the jQuery UI datepicker instead. Same markup and it worked fine. I know this technically does not answer my question - just adding some closure for those of you desperately searching for an answer and see's this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because "date" obj is not type of "string".

This error happen at code below.

```
parseDate: function(date, format) {
    var parts = date.split(format.separator),  // Error occured
    ...
}
```

The solution is to make date object as a string at forcibly.

Revised Code is below.

```
parseDate: function(date, format) {
    date = date + ""; // Add this line
    var parts = date.split(format.separator),
    ...
}
```

Good Luck!!